# Use obj + mtl blender file in Windows 8 application

Tags: windows-8, 3d, blender

I'm looking for a way to use Obj (+ mtl) files generated by blender in a Windows 8 (for Windows Store) application.

I've look at Visual Studio 3D Starter Kit but it seems to work only with obj files without mtl.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the context? Will there be just a few objects or do you plan to have large 3D scenes? The solution could range from creating a small Direct3D context and using e.g. http://assimp.sourceforge.net/ to import these files to using a game engine like OGRE.

Comment: There is few objects, multiple time (it's a 3D phone viewer, you can rotate the phone 360°), and there are plenty of phones. And each phone is made of 3 obj+mtl.